# Has this file malicious code inside?

Tags: fix-my-code

Can you please tell me if this file has some malicious code inside?

http://pastebin.com/Cg1PzSrk

Thanks.

Comment: This file is the defines.php of the administrator site and yes it is modified

Comment: That code looks like a hacked file. First try to update Joomla! and then see this: https://docs.joomla.org/Security_Checklist/You_have_been_hacked_or_defaced

Answer (score 1):

This file is the defines.php of the administrator site and yes it is modified.

This is what the original file should look like:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package    Joomla.Administrator
 *
 * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Global definitions
$parts = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, JPATH_BASE);
array_pop($parts);

// Defines
define('JPATH_ROOT',          implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $parts));
define('JPATH_SITE',          JPATH_ROOT);
define('JPATH_CONFIGURATION', JPATH_ROOT);
define('JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR', JPATH_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'administrator');
define('JPATH_LIBRARIES',     JPATH_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'libraries');
define('JPATH_PLUGINS',       JPATH_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'plugins');
define('JPATH_INSTALLATION',  JPATH_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'installation');
define('JPATH_THEMES',        JPATH_BASE . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'templates');
define('JPATH_CACHE',         JPATH_BASE . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cache');
define('JPATH_MANIFESTS',     JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'manifests');
```

Comment: The problem is that if I replace the code posted with the code you pasted the website does not pull up anymore